# How to check whether an XFeatureCall actually refers to something

Tags: xtext, eclipse-emf, emf, xtend, xbase

When I'm scanning the ast I want to check whether an element of the type
XFeatureCall can be resolved.

Concrete example:

```
val x = 2
val y = x + z
```

I know that

```
val y = <XFeatureCall> + <XFeatureCall>
```

But only the XFeatureCall "z" should give true (when applying the yet to be found predicate I'm searching).

So far I haven't been able to find a pattern. Except that every unresolvable variable satisfies the following condition:

fc means XFeatureCall

```
fc.feature instanceof JvmVoid && !fc.explicitOperationCall
```

This however is not good enough. Because it also sees "System.out.println"

Note:
I use a TreeIterator that I get from the root AST element

If necessary I will examine how the XbaseCompiler does it but I prefer not to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper check would be fc.feature.eIsProxy to check whether the feature was not resolved. What do you mean by 'It also sees System.out.println'?